# What does the 'x' in the extensions aspx, docx, xlsx, etc. represent?

Tags: ms-office

Or at least describe about.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `.aspx` I assumed it stands for:

```
Active Server Page eXtended format
```

Though another [opinion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Characteristics) is that:

> these files typically contain static (X)HTML markup, as well as markup defining server-side Web Controls and User Controls

[Apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266332.aspx) it was the `cool` thing to do at time (the quote actually talks about the original name `XSP`, but doesn't rule it out as an option):

> The initial prototype was called "XSP"; Guthrie explained in a 2007 interview that, "People would always ask what the X stood for. At the time it really didn't stand for anything. XML started with that; XSLT started with that. Everything cool seemed to start with an X, so that's what we originally named it."

For the office documents, since they are in XML format, it stands for XML.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it stands for XML.

Since XML was used heavily in .NET Framework and later on in Open XML formats for Excel, Word.

Comment: It probably does, but as a side note this isn't entirely true for .aspx, which is as much XML as classic ASP -- simply put, it's not pure XML at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I was correctly informed, it stands for 'XML' - these files are renamed, zipped XML documents. That goes for .docx, .xlsx etc.; don't know about .aspx since that's web stuff.

Answer (score 0):

They usually contain static XHTML

Answer (score -1):

This is to indicate that it is a page contains (X)HTML and the rest of the code is in the code behind (e.g. about.aspx.cs or about.aspx.vb)

Comment: To whom that gave a downvote to my answer, what is the problem, care to explain?